# Adding the input layer - units with a decimal

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I took the course Machine Learning A-Z from Udemy and am trying to apply what I learned in the tutorials.  Theye taught us in the "Adding the input layer" portion of an ANN that the units is based off of the input_dim.  Normally the "units = (input_dim + 1) / 2".  In the dataset that I am working with my input_dim=754.  (754 + 1) / 2 = 377.5.  Should I use 377.5 or should I round up or down to a whole number?

```
#Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=377.5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=754))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing between 377 and 378 input units is unlikely to be meaningfully different on out-of-sample data. Any variation is likely within the standard error of your estimate of out-of-sample performance. If you find that the difference is larger than 1 standard error, I would be concerned that the result is due to some programming error, or because one or both of the networks are very sensitive to some choice of initialization.

Comment: I will just go with 377 then, thank you for the feed back @Sycorax